# How can set childPosition to open its Activity

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created an expandable List View in Android and I don't know how I can set the childPosition to open Activity by using Intent. 
My Code of Expandable Array List Is as Bellow:

```
package com.am.expandablelist2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader; //Header Title
//Child Title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, 
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild){
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(com.am.expandablelist2.R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(com.am.expandablelist2.R.id.tvListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, 
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(com.am.expandablelist2.R.layout.list_group, null);

    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(com.am.expandablelist2.R.id.tvListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}



}
```

and My Main Activity is as bellow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get the listView
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    //Preparing List Data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    //Setting List Adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    //List View Group Click Listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
    });
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                    int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + ":" + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                return false;
            }
        });
    }


private void prepareListData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    //Adding Group Data
    listDataHeader.add("گروه E");
    listDataHeader.add("گروه F");
    listDataHeader.add("گروه C");
    listDataHeader.add("گروه D");

    //Adding Child Data
    List<String> groupE = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupE.add("EXW");


    List<String> groupF = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupF.add("FCA");
    groupF.add("FAS");
    groupF.add("FOB");

    List<String> groupC = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupC.add("CFR");
    groupC.add("CIF");
    groupC.add("CPT");
    groupC.add("CIP");

    List<String> groupD = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupD.add("DAF");
    groupD.add("DES");
    groupD.add("DEQ");
    groupD.add("DDU");
    groupD.add("DDP");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), groupE);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), groupF);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), groupC);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), groupD);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

It's my pleasure if some one can help me how Add Intent in my Main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I understand your question: 

 You want to launch activity on selecting/clicking on child list item. ?

Comment: Yes Exactly As you see I can set a Toast Message when I clicked on each Items but I don't know How I can set them to lunch activity on selecting on child list items.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Answer of My question but it would be appreciated if some one can give better solution.

Actually I add bellow code in onChildClick(ExpandableListView ... ) Method:

```
String ldc = listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
            if (ldc == "EXW") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EXW.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (ldc == "FCA") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FCA.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

please Notice I created two Activity named EXW and FCA. their name are exactly same as child Items name in my child list view. Now when I'm select each of the EXW or FCA child Items their related Activity will open. I can create an activity for each child Item same as above.